# RSpec how to mock a ZendeskAPI::Collection object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zendesk-api

I'm trying to mock a zendesk API response that's called like this:

```
zendesk_client = ZendeskHelper.make_client
tickets = zendesk_client.search.export(query)
```

The application iterates through all the pages in a Zendesk API request using the API's `.all!` method:

```
tickets.all! do |ticket|
  # do something
end
```

Initially, I put some doubles in an array and used that as a mock response:

```
mock_tickets = [
  double('ticket'),
  double('ticket'),
  double('ticket')
]

allow(mock_zendesk_client).to receive_message_chain(:search, :export).and_return(mock_tickets)
```

But I get a syntax error because a normal array cannot use the `.all!` method.

I inspected the real `tickets` response, and it was a `ZendeskAPI::Collection` object. How can I mock this object so my mock response can use the `.all!` method?

The `.all!` method looks like this

```
def all!(start_page = @options["page"], &block)
  _all(start_page, :bang, &block)
end

...

def _all(start_page = @options["page"], bang = false, &block)
  raise(ArgumentError, "must pass a block") unless block

  page(start_page)
  clear_cache

  while (bang ? fetch! : fetch)
    each do |resource|
      arguments = [resource, @options["page"] || 1]

      if block.arity >= 0
        arguments = arguments.take(block.arity)
      end

      block.call(*arguments)
    end

    last_page? ? break : self.next
  end

  page(nil)
  clear_cache
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get into a situation like you're in trying to deep-mock some third party's API response, you'll find that you're actually testing the third party's API, not your own code.

You should have a layer above the Zendesk response that's full of objects YOUR code is creating, mock THERE instead.

Comment: That makes sense, but my application is mainly just obfuscating some PII from zendesk, iterating through each ticket in the response using `.all!`, so I needed to mock the response. There aren't many layers to it

Comment: Then maybe try using vcr or webmock to actually stub out the http request/response.

Answer (score 0):

Got a suggestion from a senior dev, the solution is to mock the implementation of `.all!`.

```
mock_items = [double('mock_item')]
mock_response = double('mock_response',
  # need to have `all!` here, else you'll get error saying the double doesn't implement `.all!`
  all!: ''
)

allow(mock_response).to receive(:all) do |&block|
  # iterates through the items using the block that follows .all!
  mock_items.each do |item|
    block.call(item)
  end
end
```